# MS CRM 2011, Views filtered by teams throw error when user is not a member of any team

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, filtering, fetchxml

We have created some views that show activities assigned either to the current user OR any of the user's teams. The filtering was fairly simple:

```
Related Activity Parties
 - Party equals current user
OR
 - Party equals current user's teams
```

This works great if the user is a member of any team that's not the default. However, if the user is not a member of any team, the view throws an ugly error and doesn't show anything. The error log says "user is not a member of any teams".

I've been playing around with filters, and there seem to be alternative ways to get something similar, but nothing is quite exactly the same. If only there was more flexibility to use the OR and AND groupings.

So, has anyone run into similar issues? I'm thinking about editing the view XML directly, because then I can or/and filters freely and I'd be able to get exactly what I want. However, I'm not sure how well that all works and how would it look if you tried to edit the view in CRM after it was changed directly in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm for you that this is an issue in CRM 2011 (still an issue as of Rollup 14.) Wish I had an easy solution. Lazy way around it is to create a do-nothing team, with no security role assigned, and just put every user in it. This is a work-around, not a solution, but it will make the issue go away. Not 'elegant' but it works.

The alternative, as you suggest in your post, is writing custom FetchXML for each query you need this on but that defeats much of the benefit of the Advanced Find Query tool and makes long term maintenance and administration more difficult.